# PostgreSQL compute time difference in alternate rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres table with the following data

```
#Id Time            Setting
10x,    9/11/2018 12:01,     1
10x,    9/11/2018 12:04,     0
11x,    9/7/2018 14:47,  1
11x,    9/7/2018 14:48,  0
11x,    9/7/2018 14:49,  1
11x,    9/7/2018 14:50,  0
```

The data is already sorted in ascending order by Id, Time. 
My goal is to compute the time difference between consecutive rows where the "setting" changed from 1 to 0 for a given id. I can safely assume there are even number of rows and every row with "Setting" 1 is followed by a row with Setting "0"

Expected Output

```
# Id, Duration 
10x,  3min
11x,  1min  
11x,  1min
```

Comment: Please include your sample data as a part of the question in text form.

Comment: ```consecutive rows``` - are the rows sorted by some order? or just by time?

Comment: Added the data as you requested. Also added clarification on sort order.

Comment: Rows in a relational database are **not** sorted. The only way to get a guaranteed sort order is to use an `order by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `lag()` function as in the following case :

```
select t2.Id, 
       cast((60*cast(to_char(t2.l_time,'hh24') as int)+
                cast(to_char(t2.l_time,'mi')   as int)) as varchar)||' min'
       as Duration 
  from
(
select t1.*, 
        lag(setting) over (order by id,time) l_setting,
        time - lag(time) over (order by id,time) l_time 
  from tab t1
) t2 
where t2.setting = 0 and l_setting = 1;

id  duration
--- --------
10x  3 min
11x  1 min
11x  1 min
```

where `time` is assumed to be as a timestamp type column.

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/KIQEK88314)